# C++ deleting pointers from vector causes heap error

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, heap-memory

I have a vector of pointers to objects of my base class and then I store objects from derived class in it. The way I add pointers is quite obvious

```
std::vector<Element*> mvGates;
...
mvGates.push_back(new Node(x, y));
```

And when my program is about to be closed those pointers are freed in 'for' loop

```
 for (int i=0; i<mvGates.size(); ++i)
 {
     delete mvGates[i];
 }
```

At this line my debugger (I'm using Qt Creator) is showing a few lines like that:

```
Heap block at 14E50F50 modified at 14E50F84 past requested size of 2c
Invalid address specified to RtlFreeHeap( 00030000, 14E50F58 )
```

What can be the cause, what am I doing wrong? I know that I haven't showed you full code, since it's quite long, but maybe it is enough to tell me my mistake. Probably you will recommend me using smart pointers. I think I will do it but that doesn't answer my question - what can be wrong with this code.

EDIT:
It was a very simple mistake, you couldn't have noticed it here. In Node class I've declared `some_type array[0];`

And I've been using it as a 2 elements array. I don't know why it didn't cause a SIGSEGV but it was the thing that caused heap error.

Comment: Maybe you have already free'd the memory? Maybe you have changed one or more of the pointers? Maybe you think an object is of one child-class, but it's really of another, and you write to memory not belonging to the class (and overwrite some other objects memory)? And you *did* make your destructor `virtual`? Anyway, the problem is not in the code you show here in the question, but somewhere else.

Comment: Does your Element class implement virtual destructor?

Comment: Is your destructor of `Element` marked as `virtual`? Looking at the error messages it seems it does delete less than the actual object size (2c bytes missing), which would indicate that `Element*` is deleted, but the `Node*` destructor is not called. Which would mean, you don't have a virtual destructor in your base class.

Comment: The vector `mvGates` may have become corrupted, or there's a bug in the destructor, or you may have already deleted the nodes, or some unrelated part of memory may have become corrupted somehow, or something else may have happened. It's impossible to tell.

Comment: What's a `Node` and what's an `Element` - specifically how are they related?

Comment: You didn't specify your standard, but if you can use c++11, consider switching to smart pointers http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr 

Let the object do the bookkeeping for you, and just define the classes correctly.

Comment: Or [unique_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your std::vector contains pointers to Element class instances but your are filling it using Node class instances.
Since the compiler does not complain we can safely assume that Node extends Element.

The problem is that when you delete these elements you are referring to them as Elements. Unless you are  overriding correctly Element destructor the delete operation will call Element::~Element() and not Node::~Node()

In your class definition make sure that the destructor is virtual:

```
class Element{
   virtual ~Element(){
      //Element cleanup
   }

   //....
};
```

Comment: That for sure seems like a very likely mistake, however it's not the thing in my case. First of all, neither Element or Node allocates memory, so I don't need to define their destructors. Anyway I have those empty destructors and Element destructor is virtual.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, your are visiting each object in vector by using index, and you are deleting them. However, besides what "Pierluigi" said (the virtual ~ problem), shouldn't you visit each object and delete them by using iterator rather than by using index directly?

Answer (score -3):

You had mistaken in the incremental part. Its i++ you need not ++i.

If you use ++i, it will increment before looping into for loop so at the iterator number it is referring mvGates[i] which actually doesn't exist. Only vector ranges from 0 to length-1.

```
for (int i=0; i<mvGates.size(); i++)
{
    delete mvGates[i];
}
```

Comment: It doesn't matter in this case, both versions are fine when specified in the increment-expression of the for-loop. They are fully exceuted before the next iteration and the value is incremented nevertheless. It _would_ be an issue if it were put into the arguments for `operator[]`. Also, your statement is wrong, it is not incremented before the loop begins. `++i` increments and returns the new value, whereas `i++` increments also but returns the previous value before incrementation.